# Addition / Multiplication modulo 13

Tags: diffie-hellman, modular-arithmetic

I am currently studying the Diffie-Hellman protocol. In my lecture notes I have a generator $g=2$ and I'm in group $Z_{13}^*$ . There I calculate a remainder cycle from 1 to 12 with $r =g^i \mod 13  \forall i [0,12]$

I do not quite understand the relation between the generator and the group. This is my $Z_{13}^*$:

[image]

How is the generator in the multiplication group any different from $Z_{13}^+$?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Are you wondering why $g = 2$, a generator of $Z_{13}^*$, is also a generator of $Z_{13}^+$ (it is)? If so, have you considered finding all the generators of $Z_{13}^*$, and all the generators of $Z_{13}^+$?

Comment: I don't get the difference between $g$ being generator of $Z_{13}^*$ and $g$ being generator of $Z_{13}^+$

Comment: why are there numbers going up to 18?

Comment: The (partial) tables are for the [commutative monoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid) $({\mathbb Z_{13_\text h}},*)$ and the [Abelian group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_group) $(\mathbb Z_{13_\text h},+)$, where $13_\text h=19$, rather than for what's stated. $\;$ By definition $g$ is a generator of a finite group $(S,\circ)$ iff $g\in S$, and any $x\in S$ can be written as $x=g\circ g\circ\dots g\circ g$, for some number of terms. $\;$  Ascertain what group you are working with (including, most importantly, what the group operation is), and apply that definition.

Comment: Sorry I posted the wrong pictures; I was working in $Z_{19}$ - I updated the graphics

Comment: The first table is still not that of a group, but of the commutative monoid $({\mathbb Z_{13}},*)$ (hint: find the neutral element, then if every element has an inverse). Again, find the group you are working with, and check why $g=2$ is a generator by using the definition of that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z}^*_{13}$ is a group with 12 elements, not 13.

A [group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group) is defined by a set of elements, and a "law". The law combines two elements and yields a third one within the set. You get a group if the law fulfils some properties (the law is associative, there is a neutral element, each element has an opposite in the group).

$\mathbb{Z}_{13}$ is a group with 13 elements, using "addition modulo 13" as group law. The neutral element is $0$; the opposite of $4$ is $9$ (because $4 + 9 = 13 = 0 \mod 13$).

$\mathbb{Z}^*_{13}$ is a group that uses "*multiplication* modulo 13" as group law; it contains all the elements that are invertible modulo 13. Since 13 is prime, these are all elements of $\mathbb{Z}_{13}$ *except* $0$; so you get 12 elements (the integers $1$, $2$,... $12$ modulo $13$). The neutral element is $1$ (multiplying any element by $1$ leaves it unchanged). The opposite (traditionally called "inverse" since the law is called "multiplication") of $4$ is $10$ (because $4\times 10 = 40 = 1 \mod 13$).

A **generator** for a group is an element $g$ such that applying the law repeatedly on it ultimately yields all the group elements. In $\mathbb{Z}^*_{13}$, $2$ is a generator for the whole group: if you multiply $2$ by $2$ then you get $4$; if you multiply $4$ by $2$ you get $8$; multiply by $2$ again and you get $3$; then $6$, $12$, $11$, $9$, $5$, $10$, $7$, then $1$. You got all 12 elements. On the other hand, $8$ is not a generator for the whole group since it generates only $8$, $12$, $5$ and $1$.